# What is the most successful method to automate circular rebalancing?

Tags: lightning-network, network, nodes, lightning-network-daemon, lightning-routing

What is the most successful method to automate circular rebalancing?

We have tried the Torq and the LNDG app but so far they both do not wotk for us so we are still performing manual circular rebalancing using RTL. Please can someone suggest a tutorial on how to use Torq and or LNDG or even another method?

Thank you. :)

Orange_Bonzo

Comment: "circular rebalancing" these stuff really works?

Comment: Just In Time rebalancing makes sense if you don't hold on the HTLC for too long, it also makes it easier to reason about the benefit/risk of triggering a rebalance (since you only do so if it comes at a lower cost than what you'd get from forwarding the HTLC). It's not always possible though.

Comment: If you run lndmanagej by c-otto there are a bunch of tools and scripts for finding cheap offchain liquidity. But as antoine noted. JIT routing seems more reasonable

Comment: Hi Antoine,  Thank you for this information. Being somewhat of an adolescent newbie I am not familiar with "if you don't hold on the HTLC for too long" and also this "than what you'd get from forwarding the HTLC" We are using Umbrel and know what an HTLC is but do not know how it affeccts liquidity or how it can be used to gain more liquidity as oppsoed to a circular rebalance. Please forgive my ignorance as I have not seen this information on any of the websites I have studied or from forum posts I have received an answer too.  Thank you

Comment: In answer to "vincenzopalazzo" Yes Vincenzo Circular Rebalancing really works and we use Ride The Lightning where 100k of sats at 125 PPM (Fee rate Rebalancing) almost always works especially if you have LNBig as one of the peers you are sourcing your sats from and the peer Nicehash also works and a few others too. When that does not work we sometimes use the percent type of rebalance in RTL where 0.25 percent mostly works and sometimes up to 500k of sats will go through successfully. Best of luck to you.

Comment: Thank you Rene. We will try Carsten's lndmanagej script and see how that works. So is there any way to Automate the process of aquiring inbound liquidity that works and if not do you see any new tools being created in the future that will perform this function? Thank you for your input.